# Laravel error controller (maybe)

Tags: php, laravel

I follow tutorial Laravel on youtube and I got this error:

[image]

I didn't know how to fix it because I follow the tutorial from the start and I didn't notice anything wrong. I use `xampp`. I run with `localhost:8000/blog`.  This is my code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
        return ' hello hello';

   }
}
```

BlogController.php is my controller name.

and this is on route  web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/blog','BlogController@index' );
```

Please help me, I just get started. Thanks.

Comment: There's spaces between the start of the file and `<?php` that might mess things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is an empty space before the `<?php` tag in your controller. Remove it.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Comment: great. it works. thanks man. i didnt think that empty space could cause error.

what is the reason?

Comment: Mark the answer(whichever you want either mine or Pedro's) so people can know what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class BlogController extends Controller
    {
       public function index()
       {
            return ' hello hello';

       }
    }
```

Comment: yeah. thanks man it works.how that empty space could cause a error?

Comment: It is that you must include the class so you can recognize it, You're welcome!